# React stale error date on child components

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to have form input elements, which are uncontrolled because of our use of [jQuery UI DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [jQuery maskMoney](https://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/), render errors underneath them as soon as user types something invalid for that field, as well as disable the button on any of the errors. For some reason, [none of that is working right](https://codepen.io/mwarren/pen/aMBqVj).

**Main component**

is something like the following:

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component { 

  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      payrates: [
        new PayRate(new Date(2019, 2, 1), 0.00),
      ],
      errors : {
        rate: '',
        date: ''
      },
      currentPayRate : new PayRate() // has Rate and EffectiveDate fields
    }

    // binding done here
    this.appendValue = this.appendValue.bind(this)
    this.updateCurrentPayRate = this.updateCurrentPayRate.bind(this)
    this.updateCurrentPayRateDate = this.updateCurrentPayRateDate.bind(this)
    this.updateCurrentPayRateAmount = this.updateCurrentPayRateAmount.bind(this)
    this.validate = this.validate.bind(this)

  }

  /**
   * @param { PayRate } newPayRate
   **/
  updateCurrentPayRate(newPayRate) { 
    this.setState({
      ...this.state, 
      currentPayRate : newPayRate
    })
  }

  updateCurrentPayRateDate(dateString) {
    const newPayRate = Object.assign(new PayRate(), this.state.currentPayRate, { EffectiveDate : new Date(dateString) } )
    this.validate(newPayRate)
    this.updateCurrentPayRate(newPayRate)
  }

  updateCurrentPayRateAmount(amount) { 
    const newPayRate = Object.assign(new PayRate(), this.state.currentPayRate, { Rate : Number(amount) } )
    this.validate(newPayRate)
    this.updateCurrentPayRate(newPayRate)
  }

  /**
   * @param { PayRate } value
   **/
  appendValue(value) { 
    console.log("trying to append value: ", value)
    if (this.validate(value)) {
      this.setState({...this.state, 
                   payrates : this.state.payrates.concat(this.state.currentPayRate)})
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param { PayRate } value
   **/
  validate(value) { 
    // extract rate,date from value
    const rate = value.Rate,
          date = value.EffectiveDate

    console.log("value == ", value)

    let errors = {}

    // rate better resolve to something
    if (!rate) { 
      errors.rate = "Enter a valid pay rate amount"
    }

    // date better be valid
    if ((!date) || (!date.toLocaleDateString)) { 
      errors.date = "Enter a date"
    }
    else if (date.toLocaleDateString("en-US") === "Invalid Date") { 
      errors.date = "Enter a valid pay rate date"
    }

    console.log(errors)

    // update the state with the errors
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      errors : errors
    })

    const errorsToArray = Object.values(errors).filter((error) => error)
    return !errorsToArray.length;
  }

  render() { 
    return <div>
      <DateList dates={this.state.payrates}/>
      <NewPayRateRow 
        value={this.state.currentPayRate}
        errors={this.state.errors}
        onChange={this.updateCurrentPayRate}
        onPayRateAmountChange={this.updateCurrentPayRateAmount}
        onPayRateDateChange={this.updateCurrentPayRateDate}
        onAdd={this.appendValue}
        />

    </div>
  }
}
```

**The "form" component**

Has the following implementation:

```
class NewPayRateRow extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)

  }

  render() { 
    console.log(Object.values(this.props.errors).filter((error) => error))

    return <span class="form-inline">
        <RateField 
          errors={this.props.errors.rate}
          onKeyUp={(e) => {
            // extract the value 
            const value = e.target.value
            this.props.onPayRateAmountChange(value)
          }}
          />
        <DateInput 
          errors={this.props.errors.date}
          onChange={this.props.onPayRateDateChange}
          />
      <button onClick={(e) => {
        this.props.onAdd(this.props.value)
      }}
        disabled={Object.values(this.props.errors).filter((error) => error).length}>Add New Pay Rate</button>
    </span>
  }
}
```

**An uncontrolled input component**

where the issue definitely happens:

```
class DateInput extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);

    // do bindings
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      yearRange: "-116:+34",
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
      // telling jQuery UI to pass its event to React
      onSelect : this.handleChange
    });

  }

  componentWillUnmount() { 
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('destroy')
  }

  // handles a change to the input field
  handleChange(value) { 
    this.props.onChange(value)
  }

  render() { 
    const fieldIsInvalid = this.props.errors || ''

    return <div class="col-md-2">
      <input 
        id="datepicker"
        className={"datepicker form-control " + fieldIsInvalid }
        placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
        onChange={(e) => this.props.onChange(e.target.value) }>
      </input>
      <div>
        {this.props.errors}
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

For some reason, even though I'm selecting via the datepicker widget the value, the `errors` don't change:

[image]

However, when I go to comment out all the `validate` calls, it adds the fields no problem.

I did some caveman debugging on the `value` I was passing to `validate` to ensure that I was passing it truthy data.

Why is `this.state.error` not updating correctly, via the components?!

**UPDATE**: I went to update just the pay rate, initially, and the errors rendered correctly, and from going through the code, I found that `this.setState` was actually setting the state. However, when I went to trigger change on the input money field, `this.setState` was getting hit, and `errors` object, was empty (which is correct), but somehow, `this.setState` wasn't actually updating the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue!

**What I did**

Instead of persisting `errors` in the global `state`, and instead of passing `validate`, to set the global state, to the methods, I maintain it as function defined outside the main component's class, like this :

```
/**
 * Validates a PayRate
 * @param { PayRate } value
 * @returns { Object } any errors
 **/
function validate(value = {}) { 
  // extract rate,date from value
  const rate = value.Rate,
        date = value.EffectiveDate

  let errors = {}

  // rate better resolve to something
  if (!rate) { 
    errors.rate = "Enter a valid pay rate amount"
  }

  // date better be valid
  if ((!date) || (!date.toLocaleDateString)) { 
    errors.date = "Enter a date"
  }
  else if (date.toLocaleDateString("en-US") === "Invalid Date") { 
    errors.date = "Enter a valid pay rate date"
  }

  return errors
}
```

Note the much simpler implementation. I then no longer need to call `validate` on the `updateCurrentPayRate...` methods.

Instead, I invoke it on `NewPayRateRow.render` (which I can now do because it's not touching state at all, avoiding any invariant violation), save the result to a local const variable, called `errors`, and use that instead of `this.props.errors`. Though, truth be told, I could probably put `validate` back in `this.props` to achieve a layer of abstraction/extensibility.

Also, I took Pagoaga's advice and used `className` instead of `class` (I don't have that as muscle memory yet).

Comment: Nice job, always good to see follow-ups when people solve their own problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a "class" attribute inside several of your render functions, replacing it with "className" will allow the error to show up : https://codepen.io/BPagoaga/pen/QoMXmw

```
return <div className="col-md-2">
```

Comment: The error shows up (thank you for fixing that!), but now the issue remains of `error` state being stale after initial render